# Why does the .index() function not work?

Tags: jquery

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/ePMFe/

It returns the index as -1, instead of the actual index. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your jQuery array is the UL and you're searching for an LI.

```
console.log($("#myul li").index(tab));
```

should work fine

Answer (score 1):

index start with **0** and u want to search the index of **tab_3** then it will b `2`

see the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/ePMFe/6/)

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer your actual question, you can solve the problem by using `$(tab).index()`.